# Как сделать в android studio элемент Button или ImageButton, содержащий рисунок и текст

Tags: button

[image: Внешний вид кнопок]

Нужно сделать кнопки, имеющие цвет, в левой части - рисунок и следующий за рисунком текст.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Атрибуты Button в xml файле.

> ```
>         android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/save"
>         android:drawableStart="@mipmap/save"
>         android:text="Войти в транс"
> ```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло, всё получилось. Не могли бы Вы, если нетрудно, объяснить, чем отличаются параметры "...Left" и "...Start", и соответственно "...Right" и "...End"

Comment: Left - левая сторона. Start - левый верхний угол. Right - правая сторона, End - Правый нижний угол. Вроде так если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: ОК. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать TextView, и добавить атрибут android:drawableLeft=".."

Comment: Спасибо! Применил, всё получилось)))